# Getting 'Permission Denied' error trying to generate Doxygen documentation

Tags: cygwin, doxygen

I am trying to run the `doxygen` command (I'm using Windows 10 with Cygwin and the packages Doxygen, Graphviz and the g++ compiler installed with it) and, at the end of the execution, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not open "/cygdrive/c/Users/alexl/Desktop/src/DOC/html/graph_legend.png" for writing: Permission denied

error: Problems running dot: exit code=1, command='dot', arguments='"/cygdrive/c/Users/alexl/Desktop/src/DOC/html/graph_legend.png" -Tpng -o "/cygdrive/c/Users/alexl/Desktop/src/DOC/html/graph_legend.png"'
```

I also get sixteen other warnings with the following structure:

```
Warning: Cannot open file <filename>.png for writing
```

I've been searching for hours why this may occurr. I've tried running command prompt as an administrator, but the error still persists. Any help  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of doxygen and dot are you using? This looks a bit like a permission problem, but you ran also as administrator so should not be the cause (but please check your umask and the permissions of / in the html directory on cygwin level). Another, unlikely, possibility might be disk full / quota exceeded as the dot run is at the end of a doxygen run. When you run `doxygen -d extcmd` you will get a.o. the command to be execute for the dot command, can you try the mentioned command for one of the failing files and check what is happening.

Comment: Try to not use the `/cygdrive/c/Users/alexl/Desktop` path but instead something like `/usr/src` or `/tmp/src` . Inherited permissions could be a problem on Windows user directory

Comment: I'm using doxygen version 1.9.1 and dot version 2.40.1.  I've tried running `doxygen -d extcmd` and I get the same error message. I'm not getting any a.o. But I've noticed that when I try to run `dot grpah_legend.dot -Tpng -o graph_legend.png` I get the error `Error: Could not open "graph_legend.png" for writing: Permission denied`. That's weird. I may have to reinstall graphviz. How can I check the permissions of the html on cygwin level? @albert

Comment: cygwin has *nix commands so the easiest way is by means of `ls -ls`

Comment: I get `-rwx------+` on every file and `-rw-r--r--+` on the file `graph_legend.dot`. @albert

Comment: For the dot files I have as permission: `-rw-rw-r--` and as umask `0022`. What happens when you remove the dot files and regenerate? What is your umask?

Comment: If I remove the dot files and regenerate I get `-rw-r--r--+` for all of the files and as umask `0022` @albert

Comment: And did it regenerate the png files? otherwise also do the same for the png files. Strange that you get `-rw-r--r--+` with the umask  `0022`. When still a problem remove entire html directory and retry. It must be something specific with the settings as I don't have the problem.

Comment: So I tried what @matzeri suggested and it finally worked as expected. It must've been a problem having to do with inherited permissions on Windows user directory. Thanks for the help albert & matzeri.

Comment: Glad that it is working, those windows permissions ....